# Android: Reopen app when click on notification

Tags: android

This is the code I use to create the PendingIntent for my notification.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Activity1.class);

PendingIntent myIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
```

This PendingIntent launches Activity1 when the notification is click.
How can I simply reopen the app and go to the most recent Activity (as though clicking on the launcher icon) instead of launching a new Activity when the notification is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

> Activity1 is just an example. I have multiple Activity in the app. I just want to reopen the app and go to the most recent Activity

NOTE: this looks like wrong design for me, because notification should allow user to enter activity that is in context with the notification.

Technically, you can create redirecting activity and your notification intent should launch it when tapped. In its `onCreate()` you check what activity you want user to be redirected (you can keep this info in SharedPreferences, and each activity would write this info in `onCreate()` (or make that in your base class if you have it). Then in redirector you call regular `startActivity()` to go last activity and call `finish()` to conclude your redirector. Moreover, your redirector activity does not need any layout so add

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
```

to its Manifest entry (of course you also need no call to `setContentView()`)

Answer (score 0):

create Activity1 as a singletask activity , by changing the launchMode of the activity to singleTask...

Comment: Activity1 is just an example. I have multiple Activity in the app. I just want to reopen the app and go to the most recent Activity.

Answer (score 0):

set your activity to `launchMode="singleTop"` in your `Manifest.xml` then use this code instead of what you are using above to reopen the active one:

```
Title = "YourAppName";
Text = "open";
notificationIntent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);
cIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(getApplicationContext(), Title,   Text, cIntent);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the android:launchMode in the manifest file for the activity targeted by the pending intent.

Typically, you can use singleTop, which will reuse the same instance when the targeted activity is already on top of the task stack (i.e.: Activity is shown before you left your app).

You can also consider SingleTask and SingleInstance, if you want to keep only a single instance of the activity.